# Convert a file into Base64Binary in Axapta 3.0

Tags: axapta

I am using axapta 3.0. And want to read an image, which is encoded as Base64Binary in an xml file. 
I had tried BinData::StrtoData(str). But it is not useful. As the image is in binary type encode, not the string type encode. 
I think its easy (to deal with BinData class) in newer version of Axapta, but i want solution for Axapta 3.0.

Can someone has experience with this problem? Or know the solution to it?

Thanks in advance for help!
Kashif.

Answer (score 0):

You could interface with [Crypt32.CryptStringToBinaryA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Morten Lehrmann has an implementation [here](http://lehr.dk/dynax.php).

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: Thats was my question. but i found an inappropriate solution. Develop com object in .Net and use it in AX. :)